# What is BeautifulSoup4 adding to my SVG tags?

Tags: xml, python-3.x, svg, beautifulsoup

When I load and dump a very simple Inkscape SVG file using BeautifulSoup4, the top level SVG tag name gets `:svg` appended to it, and the XML declaration no longer has `standalone="no"`. This causes the [W3C XML validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to complain:

> No DOCTYPE found! Checking XML syntax only.

What exactly is happening here, and why does it change the validation result? How can I retain the original structure of the SVG file while still being able to operate on it?

The code to reproduce this is:

```
Python 3.3.0 (default, Sep 25 2013, 19:28:08) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> with open('ex.svg') as ip: doc = BeautifulSoup(ip, 'xml')
... 
>>> with open('out.svg', 'w') as op: op.write(doc.prettify())
... 
560
>>>
```

Original SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="0"
   height="0"
   id="template-svg"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.48.4 r"
   sodipodi:docname="template.svg">
</svg>
```

Output (manually prettified a bit):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg:svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="0"
   height="0"
   id="template-svg"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.48.4 r"
   sodipodi:docname="template.svg">
</svg:svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the top level SVG tag name gets `:svg` appended to it
>
> exactly is happening here, and why does it change the validation result?

That's not quite what's happening here. The namespace *prefix* is changing, from nothing:

```
<svg
   ...
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
```

to `svg`:

```
<svg:svg
   ...
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
```

Your original document defines two separate prefixes for the SVG namespace:

```
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
```

You may find that deleting the first causes the output to always use the original `svg:` prefix (experimentally, a random prefix is picked).

This change shouldn't make any difference to most XML consumers, but the validator you're using cares.

For finer control, consider using [lxml's BeautifulSoup parser](http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html) along with something like [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17831180/733345) to set an empty prefix for that namespace in the output.

Comment: So the big question for me is really just: does it have a functional effect on the XML? And I think you answered that with "shouldn't make a difference to most XML consumers...". I'm not too worried about how it looks under the hood, just curious as to whether it's still well-formed and valid.

Comment: It's still well-formed, it's still a [Conforming SVG Stand-Alone File](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/conform.html#ConformingSVGStandAloneFiles), but it won't validate against the SVG DTDs. Unless you specifically need that, you should be fine.